# Does Forbidden Words affect the character or player or both?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

In mansions of madness 2nd edition, there is an insanity card called 'Forbidden Words'.  The text specifies "You cannot speak.  You win or lose the game as normal."  There was some confusion as to if 'you' meant the player or the character.  That is, must the player stop talking or can the character no longer interact with person tokens on the map? Or is it both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My take was that the physical player is not allowed to speak anymore, as else I think there would be specific instructions like you cannot use spells anymore. I think the goal is to create a more interesting interaction by forcing the player to communicate with gestures/pointing on the board.

Comment: This is how we've been playing it as well.  Lacking any other information, this will have to be the correct answer.  I really dislike this card though, as within a group, once the card has happened once, everyone knows how it works, and removes some of the fun "what kind of insane is that player" questions.

Comment: @Tal my group had run into that problem, but it evolved once they realized they could fake having the "Forbidden Words", to run around freely acting on their actual Insanity card. So now we keep asking our selves if some one is actually mute or not.